# Hibernate: A long read-only transaction will now require a small DB update in the middle

Tags: java, hibernate

I have written quite a complicated engine of sorts which navigates up and down a large series of objects read in from the database.

So I have code that looks something like this:

```
public void go(long id) {
    try {
        beginTransaction();
        Foo foo = someDao.find(id);
        anotherObject.doSomething(foo);
        commitTransaction();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        rollbackTransaction();
    }
}
```

The code in doSomething(...) will call methods to get child objects of Foo and pass those child objects off to other classes and so on.

Prior to my problem, this use to just be a long read-only transaction.  Now however, somewhere in the middle of all of this, there needs to be an update to the database.  It is important that this update is committed straight away.  As Hibernate doesn't support nested transactions, how would I deal with a situation like this to allow me to continue to pass my object around and still call getter methods to access children whilst having that database update get committed?

I thought of removing the long running transaction and having small transactions all over the place.  Unfortunately, my code at the moment passes Foo and other child objects everywhere assuming it is still bound to the session.  If this is my only solution, would that mean I would end up with ugly merge calls everywhere just to re-attach to the session so the getter methods work again?  I'm sure there must be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've bitten the bullet and I believe splitting up the big transaction into smaller transactions to have more atomicity is best.  This required some manual eager loading in the code however but my nested transaction issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Do the database update within your transaction, i.e. pass the required information to the thread performing your long transaction.

Alternatively, use [entity listeners](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html) to signal what needs update, and then use the EntityManager.refresh method.

This will be getting a bit ugly with multi-threading and all, but note that you probably do not want the transaction to 'just update' at some random point in time, as that in many cases will yield unpredictable results, like breaking for-loops and such.

And if this is a n-level algorithm, is there any way of doing m levels at a time, save the state (say, the id's of the current scope), and run the next iteration in a new transaction? For this you can use one method without a transaction, which calls EJBs methods which are confined within their own transaction, returning state.

Answer (score 0):

If you must stick with Hibernate (and cannot consider accessing the underlying JDBC driver, Spring Transactions or JTA), you can probably just spawn a thread to do the update and have the main thread wait until it's done (Thread.join()).

Comment: I've tried this but in just seems to stall on committing the update.

Comment: if you are on SERIALIZABLE isolation, the open transaction could be locking the rows read by it and preventing the update. Anything lower than that should work. Your database should also be able to tell you why it can't commit the transaction (i.e. what locks it's waiting on).